# How can I check if file exists in ccperl?

Tags: perl, batch-file, clearcase

I need to check if file exists in ccperl.

I tried to use 'if exists' but it didn't work.

I know sometimes we use " ' " in the beginning and the end of the command, but is there another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you probably want is `-f 'myfile'`, which returns true if the name corresponds to a file.

There is [a number of these tests](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html), and you can use `-e` to check that the name exists, but it could be either a file or a directory (or perhaps a link or a pipe on Unix).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [ccperl (or ratpl)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21245227), check the version of the perl used (for old ClearCase versions, it is still a 5.8.6).
That can have an influence on using certain files tested with `-f`, as [this thread illustrates from a file with a trailing space](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.beginners/2007/10/msg96549.html).

You can see an example of [ClearCase ccperl script here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=41198):

```
if ( $n_file != 0 ) {
  while ( $file_name = shift(@file_list) )
  {
    if ( ! -f $vob_path.$dir_part.'/'.$file_name ) {
      print "not found $vob_path".$dir_part.'/'."$file_name \n";
    } else {
      $size1 = &file_size($file_name);
      $size2 = &file_size($vob_path.$dir_part.'/'.$file_name);
      if ( $size1 != $size2 ) {
        print "Err file $dir_part $file_name $size1 $size2\n";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(it would test also for directories, a few line below, with the `-d` option)